# Connect MySQL DB on EC2 from Fargate Container application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, aws-security-group

I have a container application running on ECS Fargate (Network awsvpc), And tried to connect MySQL database set up on EC2 instance... But it is not happening.

I can connect same database (on EC2) from local machine with same containerized application running.

Trying so hard to solve this issue, if you know please help me.
Tried other things I know:

- Security group inbound as ECS service security group (also tried opening all traffic access to EC2 instance)
- ECS tasks running into private subnet or public subnet (EC2 and Fargate apps, all are in same VPC)

Comment: Make sure you are using the private IP of the EC2 server when connecting from the ECS instance.

Comment: Thank you, it was because of Public IP I'm using... Now it's working perfectly...